# Change color and theme of fab button

Tags: android

I used custom style resource and used the following code to change the theme which changes action bar and status bar color but fab button theme doesn't change.
`getTheme().applyStyle(switchValue? R.style.AppTheme1:R.style.AppTheme2 , true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of Floating action button is defaulted to `colorAccent` you can change this from code.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList
                .valueOf(getResources()
                        .getColor(colorsArray[themeId],getTheme())));
    }
```

the valueOf method in the above code takes color of type `int`

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList
                .valueOf(YourColorValue)));
    }
```